# Code generator error .g.cs this.bindings = bindings

Tags: winui-3

I'm running into a problem while developing a WinUI3 app.

Every now and then the .g.cs file contains a line which causes an error. (this.Bindings = bindings;) Sometimes when I delete it I can just run the app, sometimes it appears again.

Does anyone know what might be the problem here?

[image]

Comment: It probably comes from something in your corresponding XAML markup code. Removing it here is useless since it's generated, you'll have to find what the thing in XAML that generates it. Experience showed me the XAML => C# "compiler" has lots of issues like that once you create some fancy advanced bindinds (x:Bind, etc.) ... Also make sure you updated all WinUI3 + WinAppSDK to latest nugets

Comment: Wish it would tell me what.... Weird that it doesn't generate the code 100% of the time though. 

Will try, thanks for the tips.

Comment: Seems to be solved after upgrading the SDK